# Javascript crashes on adding a line of code

Tags: javascript, html, css, ccss

Okay here is my javascript.
When i add the variable angle1 to my javascript it crashes the whole javascript. basicy what i want is, That the image of jhin is gonna rotate on mouseover. and when the mouse goes off jhin that it then rotate backs to the original. (invisible)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow")
});

var angle = 0, img = document.getElementById('flip');
  document.getElementById('flip').onclick = function() {
  angle = (angle+180)%360;
  img.className = "rotate"+angle;
}

setTimeout(function(){
   document.body.className="";
 },900);


 var angle1 = 90 document.getElementById('jhin');
    docmument.getElementById('jhin').onclick = function() {
    angle1 = (angle1+90)%180;
    img.className = "rotate"+angle1;
  }

  });

function jhinIn(){
  document.getElementById("jhin").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function jhinOff(){
    document.getElementById("jhin").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

css:

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #700000;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#mondriaan1 {
     position: absolute;
     height: 100px;
     width: 990px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     border-color: black;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-style: solid;
}

#mondriaan2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 105px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}

#mondriaan3 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 85px;
    position: absolute;
}

#mondriaan4 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 105px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
}

#mondriaan5 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 105px;
    left: 105px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 191px;
}

#mondriaan6 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 105px;
    left: 460px;
    width: 401px;
    height: 100px;
}

#mondriaan7 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 210px;
    left: 460px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 84px;
}

#mondriaan8 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 105px;
    width: 126px;
    height: 400px;
}

#mondriaan9 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;    
    background-color: #FF3333;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 126px;
    height: 485px;
    top: 0px;
}

#mondriaan10 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 131px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 350px;
    bottom: 210px;
}

#mondriaan11 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 281px;
    width: 199px;
    height: 400px;
    bottom: 300px;
}

#mondriaan12 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 281px;
    width: 199px;
    height: 195px;
    top: 90px;
}

#mondriaan13 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 405px;
    width: 454px;
    height: 85px;
    top: 0px;
}

#mondriaan14 {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 131px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 335px;
    top: 90px;
}

#panel {
    height: 598px;
    width: 396px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    border: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #black;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    display: none;
    text-align: center; 
}

#flip {
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 176px;
     width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}

#link {
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
}


#flip {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#flip.rotate180 {
    animation-name: rotate180;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}


@keyframes rotate180 {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

body.preload *{
animation-duration: 0s !important;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;
transition:background-color 0s, opacity 0s, color 0s, width 0s, height           0s, padding 0s, margin 0s !important;}

#jhin {
    width: 199px;
    height: 400px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#jhin.rotate90 {
    animation-name: jhin90;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-timing-function: linear; 
}

@keyframes jhin90 {
    0% {transform: rotateY(90deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
}

@keyframes jhin180 {
    0% {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateY(90deg);}
}

#jhin.rotate180 {
    animation-name: jhin180;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: `var angle1 = 90 document.getElementById('jhin');` Kindly double-check it.

Comment: `var angle1 = 90 document.getElementById('jhin');` check it. you forgot to put `;` after `var angle1= 90`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var angle1 = 90 document.getElementById('jhin');
```

should be

```
var angle1 = document.getElementById('jhin');
```